# Extract only date from a DateTime column asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

in the SqlDataSource, I have specified a SelectCommand that retrieves a date:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [training_id], Convert(varchar(14),[trainingDate],101) FROM [tbl_training]"
```

However DateGenerated gives me a value like 11/04/2011 12:00:00 AM. How do I extract only 11/25/2011 using SelectCommand?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version fo SqlServer? (is it Sql Server?)

Comment: in this case you can cast dateTime to the built in Sql Server `date` type, see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify a size, try

```
Convert(varchar,[trainingDate],101)
```

If you were to run this on SQL Server for today you would get:

```
Declare @datey datetime
Set @datey = GETDATE()
Select CONVERT(varchar, @datey, 101) as [DateOnly]
```

Result:
11/04/2011

Its also worthwhile to note in SQL Server Denali all these magic numbers for formatting will go away with the new [FORMAT()](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/ana/archive/2011/09/02/sql-server-denali-format-string-function.aspx) function

Comment: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'trainingDate'

Comment: Format `111` would be better here, I think.

Comment: @user959443 you need to specify Select Convert(varchar, [trainingDate], 101) as trainingDate in your query.

Answer (score 3):

The value retrieved as a `DateTime` will *always* include a time, because that's how the type is defined. You can:

- Use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property to *ensure* you get a `DateTime` value at midnight (e.g. for equality calculations)
- Ignore the time part when formatting for the user. To format a `DateTime` to only display the date in a culture-sensitive way, you should use the "d" or "D" [standard date/time format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx). Don't hard-code a custom date/time format string unless you're *sure* that's what your users expect. (11/4/2011 looks like April 11th to me, for example...)

How else do you want to use the value? While I think it's a [fundamental flaw that `DateTime` is used for several different things](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html), you should be able to work around it if you're careful.

Answer (score 1):

if you are going to display it in an asp grid you can do this on the boundfield.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="datafield" HeaderText="displayText" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"  HtmlEncode="false"/>
```

but if you want it in the select query

```
Select convert(varchar,trainingDate, 101) as trainingDate
```

Comment: I only need to bind to a dropdown list the values from sql server datetime column but dont want the hours two show

Answer (score 1):

To get only the date part, you can do this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
dt = dt.Date;
```

If you're displaying the date, you can use `MM/dd/yyyy` format. If you want to return only the date part from SQL Server, use format `111` instead of `101`.

Answer (score 1):

```
string today_date = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

Hover over today date you will get the date part.

Answer (score 0):

Use CONVERT http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In case of Sql Server 2008 you can cast to built in [date type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx):

```
CAST(trainingDate as DATE)
```

Final query:

```
SELECT training_id, CAST(trainingDate as DATE) 
FROM tbl_training
```

Comment: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Type DATE is not a defined system type.

Comment: @user959443 : are you sure that version of server is 2008 ?